# How does OnLive work, and is there anything special Game Developers need to do?

Tags: networking, rendering, client-server

The [OnLive](http://blog.onlive.com/) service works by "cloud rendering", which is very different from the traditional model of "on-premise rendering" that we are all familiar with.  How does this work at a technical level, and is there anything special game developers or artists need to do to optimize their game for the platform?  As a developer, I'm a bit skeptical that everything is as magically working as they seem to suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The released a SDK for independant developers.

> The OnLive developer community is
>   growing rapidly, with many, many
>   titles in the works. If you’re an
>   Indie developer interested in
>   accessing our vibrant, growing
>   community, check out our partner page
>   or email us at partners@onlive.com to
>   request the OnLive SDK.

Source http://blog.onlive.com/2010/09/15/celebrating-independent-game-developers/

You "just" have to write a wrapper for your game so OnLive can communicate with your program.

Comment: Could you provide more details about this SDK?  What are some of it's plusses / minuses / benefits / drawbacks?

Comment: They haven't published any documentation publicly, so I doubt anyone here has more information (or if they do, they likely can't share it). It's probably the standard platform holder crap - demos, video recording, unlocks, achievements, etc. It's not like it's a replacement for anything else you'd do.

Comment: Details? You have to apply @ their website.
Plus / Minus?
None, as far as I can say. You just wrap your code to be interpretable by the OnLive Cloud.
You do not have to worry about that much performance etc. as I belief.

Comment: "check out our partner page or email us at partners@onlive.com to request the OnLive SDK"
The quote says everything